# ¿Es necesario cerrar una conexión con PDO luego de ejecutar una sentencia?

Tags: php, pdo

Me gustaría saber si tengo que cerrar una conexión abierta con PDO luego de ejecutar el script CRUD.

He leído que no es necesario cerrarla explícitamente, pero también he leído que es mejor cerrar la conexión para evitar cargar el servidor con tantas conexiones abiertas. La verdad ahora no sé que pensar con todo esto y si cierro o no las conexiones.

Comment: ¿Podrías describir con más detalle cuál es la lógica general de tu script? Por favor agrega las partes relevantes del código

Answer (score 8):

En teoría, una conexión PDO se cierra ella sola al ejecutar la última sentencia del script que usa dicha conexión, por lo que si tu código está bien concebido no tendrías que preocuparte de cerrar las conexiones.

De la [ayuda PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php):

> Una vez realizada con éxito una conexión a la base de datos, será devuelta una instancia de la clase PDO al script. **La conexión permanecerá activa durante el tiempo de vida del objeto PDO**. Para cerrar la conexión, es necesario destruir el objeto asegurándose de que todas las referencias a él existentes sean eliminadas; esto se puede hacer asignando `NULL` a la variable que contiene el objeto. **Si no se realiza explícitamente, PHP cerrará automáticamente la conexión cuando el script finalice**.
>
> Nota: Si aún existen otras referencias a esta instancia de PDO (tales como desde una instancia de `PDOStatement`, o desde otras variables que hacen referencia a la misma instancia de PDO), estas también han de eliminarse (por ejemplo, asignando `NULL` a la variable que hace referencia al `PDOStatement`).

De todos modos, algunos recomiendan, más por constumbre que por otra cosa, cerrar las conexiones PDO una vez usadas. Si te decides por cerrar tus conexiones debes asignar `null` no sólo a la conexión, sino a todo aquello que haga referencia a dicha conexión, como explica el segundo párrafo de la nota indicada más arriba.

Hay discusiones también sobre **si conviene más una conexión persistente o conectarse cada vez a la base de datos**. No hay una respuesta definitiva, depende de cada caso, necesidad y entorno de desarrollo.

Sobre conexiones persistentes puedes leer los siguientes enlaces en el Manual de PHP:

- [Conexiones persistentes a bases de datos](http://php.net/manual/es/features.persistent-connections.php)
- [Conexiones y su administración](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php)

En mi caso, uso una clase PDO en mi página web con conexión persistente y hasta ahora no he tenido ningún problema. Sencillamente la clase que maneja las conexiones investiga primero si no hay alguna conexión ya disponible y si no la hay entonces crea una nueva. De modo que sólo pido mi conexión y hago mis consultas, vigilando que el código esté optimizado, su flujo controlado y que el script termine cuando tenga que terminar... evitando llamar mi conexión desde bucles que por cualquier motivo podrían terminar siendo interminables, etc.

Te muestro el método que hace esto:

```
public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance == null) {
            $className = __CLASS__;
            self::$instance = new $className();
        }
        return self::$instance;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Las sesiones mueren cuando termina de ejecutarse tu script. Esto es deliberadamente así porque PHP es un lenguaje que ejecuta su script (y todo los que éste llame) en cada request. Un ciclo de una pasada que empieza de cero y no conoce nada sobre el request anterior ni el siguiente.

Si las conexiones PDO fueran persistentes, a la manera de un pool de conexiones, podría pasar que un request PHP dejara una transacción abierta, más un conjunto de sentencias, y que por un error en el script este saliera anticipadamente sin que se ejecutase el COMMIT de la transacción.

El request siguiente, que podría ser de otro usuario, podría heredar esa conexión y ejecutar simplemente COMMIT o ROLLBACK, mezclándose las acciones de ambos usuarios en una sola transacción. Evidentemente es un comportamiento no esperado e indeseable. La capa de software tiene que estar construida alrededor de una conexión persistente a nivel de arquitectura para asegurar que esto no pase, y PDO no está construido para ello.

Cerrar la conexión como último paso antes de la salida no es una mala práctica, pero no es necesaria y según algunos es una micro-optimización que no paga el tiempo que invertiste en ello.

Answer (score 2):

Yo la cierro después de utilizar los métodos de consultas que tengo en la clase DBConnect, la cual tiene los códigos de conexión en su constructor.

En esa misma clase hay un método `break_connection` que tiene `unset(self:$connex)`, donde:

- `$connex` contiene el objeto PDO de conexión que se inicia en el constructor.
- De manera que `unset()`; destruye TODO su contenido