# Forma eficiente de gestionar errores al ejecutar sentencias con PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con PHP y realizo este tipo de consultas:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
// Bindeo algunos parametros...
$stmt.execute();
```

Quiero saber cuál es la forma más eficiente de gestionar cualquier tipo de error que pueda llegar a ocurrir al hacer la consulta, ya sea esa que escribí, o un `insert()`, un `executeUpdate()`, etc. Ya que no sé si arrojan excepciones o simplemente alcanza con validar los valores de retorno.

¿Cuál forma es la más completa para gestionar estos errores?

```
if($stmt.execute()) 
    echo "Exito!";
else
    echo "Falló";
```

O atender excepciones:

```
try {
    $stmt.execute();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

¿Combinar ambas? ¿Cambia algo si son operaciones de inserción o update?

Comment: Hay que tomar ciertas precauciones con las excepciones al usar PDO. Te recomendaría usar **una única clase** que gestione tu conexión a PDO en la cual configures de forma correcta cómo PDO debe manejar las excepciones, y establezcas a FALSE las preparaciones emuladas. Mal configurado PDO podría revelar las contraseñas en el log si hay error. Pero bien configurado, controlar el código es muy fácil. No necesitarías usar bloques `try  catch` (sólo en la Clase)` sino solo evaluar el `$stmt` o el `$result` según el caso. Cuando esté en mejores condiciones proporcionaré una respuesta con ejemplos.

Comment: ¿A qué se debe que alguien haya marcado la pregunta para cierre sin siquiera comentar el por qué? Se trata de una pregunta interesante.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Al usar PDO hay que tener en cuenta dos aspectos muy importantes que atañen a la seguridad del manejo de los datos. Uno de ellos tiene que ver precisamente con el manejo de las excepciones.

---

## I

Antes de ver esos dos aspectos, quiero decir primero que la mejor manera de usar PDO es **tener una clase dedicada al manejo de nuestra conexión a PDO**, la cual usaremos cada vez que necesitemos conectarnos a la base de datos. Eso nos evita tener **cada vez** que crear el objeto PDO, configurarlo adecuadamente, etc, etc. Teniendo una clase simplemente obtenemos nuestro objeto mediante la palabra clave `new`  y listo. Además, podemos dotar a esa clase de métodos personalizados según nuestras necesidades, el binding y otras cosas se podrían simplificar de una forma interesante, dando muchísima facilidad a nuestro código.

Si se quiere, se puede echar una mirada a [**esta Clase**](https://github.com/padrecedano/PHP-PDO) que estoy creando, y que funciona ahora perfectamente para un uso básico de PDO.

Veamos entonces esos dos aspectos mencionados anteriormente:

### 1. **El manejo de las excepciones y un posible peligro**

Cuando creamos la conexión a PDO, si no se pasan los parámetros adecuados al momento de crear el objeto de conexión, PDO **podría revelar las credenciales de conexión (nombre de usuario, contraseña, nombre de la base de datos...) en el `error_log` en caso de ocurrir un error**. El registro de errores, no está de más decirlo, es uno de los archivos preferidos de cualquier hacker, precisamente porque en él se pueden encontrar datos interesantes para cualquier usuario mal intencionado.

**¿Cómo evitarlo?**

Estableciendo el siguiente parámetro en la conexión: `PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. Para más detalles ver, en el Manual de PHP: [Errores y su manejo](http://php.net/manual/es/pdo.error-handling.php)

Este sería entonces unos de los atributos que habría que pasar en opción a la conexión PDO.

Veámoslo aquí, este sería el método de conexión de una Clase dedicada a gestionar nuestra conexión PDO. Este es el método de la clase mencionada más arriba:

```
    private function Connect()
    {
    /* Leer credenciales desde el  archivo ini */
        $this->credenciales = parse_ini_file("//home3/deiverbu/.credentials/db.php.ini");
        $dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $this->credenciales["dbnombre"] . ';host=' . $this->credenciales["host"] . '';
        $pwd = $this->credenciales["clave"];
        $usr = $this->credenciales["usuario"];

    /**
     *  El array $options es muy importante para tener un PDO bien configurado
     *  
     *  1. PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true: sirve para usar conexiones persistentes
     *      se puede establecer a false si no se quiere usar este tipo de conexión. Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967 
     *  2. PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false: Se usa para desactivar emulación de consultas preparadas 
     *      forzando el uso real de consultas preparadas. 
     *      Es muy importante establecerlo a false para prevenir Inyección SQL. Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967
     *  3. PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION También muy importante para un correcto manejo de las excepciones. 
     *      Si no se usa bien, cuando hay algún error este se podría escribir en el log revelando datos como la contraseña !!!
     *  4. PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'": establece el juego de caracteres a utf8, 
     *      evitando caracteres extraños en pantalla. Ver: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/59510/29967
     */
        $options = array(
            PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, 
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, 
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, 
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"
        );
        try {
            # Intentar la conexión 
            $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $usr, $pwd, $options);

            # Conexión exitosa, asignar true a la variable booleana isConnected.
            $this->isConnected = true;
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            # Escribir posibles excepciones en el error_log
        error_log($this->error = $e->getMessage(),0);
    }
    }
```

### 2. **El problema de las preparaciones emuladas**

El segundo aspecto importante tiene que ver con las consultas preparadas y las preparaciones emuladas.

Sobre **`PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES`** el Manual dice lo siguiente:

> Habilita o deshabilita la emulación de sentencias preparadas. Algunos
>   controladores no admiten instrucciones preparadas nativas o tienen un
>   soporte limitado para ellas. Utilice esta configuración para obligar a
>   PDO a emular siempre instrucciones preparadas (si es VERDADERO), o
>   intentar utilizar instrucciones preparadas nativas (si FALSO). Siempre
>   volverá a emular la instrucción preparada si el controlador no puede
>   preparar con éxito la consulta actual.

**¿Cuál es el problema?**

Que en PDO esta opción viene establecida a `true`por defecto, y si no la establecemos a `false` al momento de crear el objeto conexión, podríamos tener una Inyección SQL preparada inteligentemente por un usario mal intencionado.

La forma en que esto podría ocurrir, esta explicado con todo detalle y ejemplos en mi respuesta a la pregunta: [¿Cómo evitar la inyección SQL en PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/53280/29967).

Por eso, verán que en el código de conexión de más arriba, tenemos esto:

```
PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
```

Si esto no está, sencillamente nuestro objeto conexión **no es del todo seguro** y podríamos llevarnos tarde o temprano la sorpresa de una Inyección SQL aunque estemos usando PDO.

---

## II

Pasemos ahora a una segunda parte que respondería más directamente a tu pregunta.

Si en nuestra clase de conexión tenemos un bloque `try ... catch` como el mostrado más arriba, podemos olvidarnos de seguir usándolo **caaaada vez** que tengamos que hacer una consulta a la base de datos. De eso se encargará la clase, que para eso existe. Nosotros tendremos que ocuparnos solamente de crear nuestro objeto conexión mediante `new`, hacer las consultas llamando a los métodos de la clase y manejar los datos.

### **Algunos usos básicos, usando nuestro objeto conexión**

#### Un `SELECT` sin criterios

Se haría sencillamente así:

```
$datos = $mipdo->query("SELECT * FROM padres");
```

Y para verificar si hay datos o no en el `SELECT`

```
if ($datos) 
{
    echo "Hay datos";
}
else
{
    echo "NO hay datos";    
}
```

#### Un `SELECT` con criterios

```
$id_provincia=1;
$id_estado=5;
$sql= "SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id_provincia = :id_provincia AND id_estado = :id_estado;";

$mipdo->bind("id_provincia", $id_provincia);
$mipdo->bind("id_estado",$id_estado);
$datos=$mipdo->query($sql);
```

Y para saber si hay datos, verificamos, como más arriba, nuestra variable `$datos`.

#### Un `UPDATE` cualquiera

```
$id_provincia=1;
$id_estado=5;

$sql= "UPDATE tabla SET id_provincia=:id_provincia WHERE id_estado=:id_estado;";
$mipdo->bind("id_provincia", $id_provincia);
$mipdo->bind("id_estado",$id_estado);
$datos=$mipdo->query($sql);
```

Para verificar si se actualizaron registros, sólo tenemos que evaluar la variable datos, como hemos hecho antes, con la diferencia de que en el caso de `UPDATE`, en caso de haber actualizaciones, la variable contendrá el total de ellas. Entonces:

```
if ($datos) 
{
    echo "Se actualizaron ".$datos." registros";
}
else
{
    echo "NO se actualizaron registros";    
}
```

#### Un `INSERT` cualquiera

```
$id_provincia=2;
$id_estado=6;

$sql= "INSERT INTO tabla (id_provincia, id_estado) VALUES (:id_provincia, :id_estado;";
$mipdo->bind("id_provincia", $id_provincia);
$mipdo->bind("id_estado",$id_estado);
$datos=$mipdo->query($sql);
```

Para verificar si se insertaron registros, sólo tenemos que evaluar la variable datos, como hemos hecho antes en el caso de `UPDATE`. Entonces:

```
if ($datos) 
{
    echo "Se insertaron ".$datos." registros";
}
else
{
    echo "NO se insertaron registros";    
}
```

---

## Conclusión

Como se puede apreciar, el uso de una clase dedicada simplifica cualquier posterior manejo de los datos. Y la clase se quiere personalizar si se desean hacer otras verificaciones, según las necesidades del programador.

Comment: Excelentes detalles en la explicación y la implementación! Gracias!

Answer (score 2):

```
try
{
    $stmt = $connection -> prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE EMAIL = :email");
    $stmt -> bindParam(':email', $username);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $rows = $stmt -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $stmt -> closeCursor();
}

catch(Exception $exception)
{
    $error = $exception -> getMessage();

    $for = "email@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Error";
    $message = "Error: " . $error;
    $headers = 'From: mail@bsvecologic.mx' . "\r\n" .
               'Reply-To: mail@bsvecologic.mx' . "\r\n" .
               'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($for, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por responder y por el ejemplo!

Answer (score 1):

Creo que estas tomando dos tipos de errores diferentes, y como tal deben tratarse diferente.

Una cosa es un posible error de conexión, que se puede dar por múltiples razones y otro muy distinto es que un `select` sea incorrecto o que la sentencia no este correctamente escrita.

En estos casos lo que te recomiendo es que uses `try {} catch()` siempre cuando crees la conexión y unicamente en las querys en las que sea necesario realizar alguna otra acción en caso de fallo, como por ejemplo:

```
try {
    $rs = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO ficheros (id, nombre) VALUES (?, ?)');
    $rs->execute([1, '/var/tmp/mifichero']);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    unlink('/var/tmp/mifichero');
    throw $e;
}
```

Por el contrario, si lo que quieres es tener controladas todas las posibles excepciones y mostrárselas al los usuarios sin las horribles tracas de una excepción, puedes usar lo siguiente:

http://www.php.net/set-exception-handler

Comment: Gracias por responder y por el ejemplo!