# PHP Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php

He revisado todos los hilos creados para este error, pero no consigo aclararme.
He creado una función que ejecuta una consulta SQL

```
function return_field_data($pdo, $tbl, $fld, $val) {
    try {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM {$tbl} WHERE {$fld}=:value";
        $stmnt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute([':value'=>$val]);
        return $stmnt->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Luego utilizo esa función para hacer un bucle `foreach`, que debería devolverme un array:

```
$result = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM user_group_link WHERE group_id='{$group_id}'");
foreach ($result as $row) {
        $user_row=return_field_data($pdo, "users", "id", $row['user_id']);
        echo "<tr><td>{$user_row['apellidos']}, {$user_row['nombre']}</td>
        <td>{$user_row['usuario']}</td>
        ";
        }
```

Sin embargo, lo que obtengo es un error

```
PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool
```

¿Dónde está el error y cómo puedo corregirlo?

Comment: hay que validar de que archivo y que linea o consulta es la que esta retornando el null o false... eso es lo que quiere decir ese error...

Comment: esto `"SELECT * FROM {$tbl} WHERE {$fld}=:value";` deberia de ser: `"SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE $fld=:value";` no tienen sentido las llavez `{` `}` en este caso.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que cuando la consulta es correcta devuelve un array, pero cuando falla devuelve una excepción y entonces da un error ya que no es un array.

Deberías hacer algo así:

```
function return_field_data($pdo, $tbl, $fld, $val) {
    try {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl WHERE $fld=:value";
        $stmnt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute([':value'=>$val]);
        return $stmnt->fetch();
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return false; // <== CAMBIAR AQUI
    }
}
```

y en la llamada

```
$result = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM user_group_link WHERE group_id='{$group_id}'");
if($result !== false){ // <== AÑADIR ESTO
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $user_row=return_field_data($pdo, "users", "id", $row['user_id']);
        echo "<tr><td>{$user_row['apellidos']}, {$user_row['nombre']}</td>
        <td>{$user_row['usuario']}</td>
        ";
        }
} else { // <== AÑADIR ESTO
    print("Se ha producido un error");
}
```

Las llaves en la asignación a $sql no son necesarias ya que sólo lo son si lo que se pasa es un array, pero no deberían dar problemas, aunque yo las quitaría.

Answer (score 3):

En primer lugar, doy por hecho que tienes configurado adecuamente el manejo de excepciones en tu actual conexión (para más detalles puedes consultar el **apartado I** de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/80986/29967)).

Dicho eso, la advertencia *`PHP Warning:  Trying to access array offset on value of type bool`* te está diciendo que hay un valor booleano que intentas leer como si fuera un array. En el fondo tu problema es la *programación optimista*. Es decir, en un cierto punto asumes que la función retornará un array sí o sí, cosa que no ocurre siempre, o que no garantizas desde la función.

Para resolverlo, tú puedes implementar una respuesta en forma de array con una clave `success` que será `true` solamente cuando haya datos.

Por ejemplo:

```
function return_field_data($pdo, $tbl, $fld, $val) {
    try {
        $sql="SELECT * FROM {$tbl} WHERE {$fld}=:value";
        $stmnt=$pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmnt->execute([':value'=>$val]);
        $row=$stmnt->fetch();
        if ($row) {
            $data=array('success'=>true, 'data'=>$row);
        } else {
            $data=array('success'=>false, 'msg'=>'no se encontraron filas');
        }
        return $data;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        return array('success'=>false, 'msg'=>$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Y en el contexto donde recibes la llamada a la función:

```
$result = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM user_group_link WHERE group_id='{$group_id}'");


    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $data=return_field_data($pdo, "users", "id", $row['user_id']);
        /*
          Según la lógica seguida en la función, 
          la clave success de $data sólo será verdadera
          cuando haya datos, de lo contrario será false
          y tendrá asociada una clave msg con un texto
          descriptivo del mensaje
        */
        if ($data['success']) {
            $user=$data['data'];
            printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",$user['apellidos'],$user['nombre'],$user['usuario']);
        } else {
            echo $data['msg'];
        }
    }
```

Sea como sea, hay lagunas en tu código, sospechas de falta de optimización y agujeros de seguridad, tres aspectos no negligible si quieres escribir un buen programa.

Por ejemplo, ¿qué sentido tiene la consulta previa, ejecutada además de una forma totalmente insegura al no usar consultas preparadas? ¿Acaso no es mejor ejecutar una sola consulta que ponga en relación esa consulta inicial con las sucesivas consultas que llamas una y otra vez en bucle? Haciendo eso optimizarías y darías seguridad al código.

Por otra parte, dentro del bucle abres un `tr` que nunca cierras ¿? Supongo que estás en el contexto de una tabla HTML, pero ¿qué ocurre en el caso de error? En el código, para simplificar, yo he puesto esto: `echo $data['msg'];` que imprimiría el mensaje de error, pero, ahí estamos en el contexto de una tabla ... Te aconsejo que acoples mejor el código, evaluando los errores, en cuyo caso no imprimirías la tabla, sino un mensaje de error. Dado que no hay más contexto, no he aportado nada al respecto.

Lo que quiero que entiendas, cuando hablo del error llamado *programación optimista*, es que un programa que no maneja adecuadamente los errores no será nunca un programa maduro ... es más, será un programa mal escrito, deficiente. Él será una maravilla cuando todo vaya bien (programación optimista), pero en cuanto algo vaya mal, se revelarán las deficiencias de ese programa a no prever manejo adecuado de errores.

Comment: Magnífica respuesta y excelente explicación. Procuraré actuar en consecuencia. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @jpinilla se me escapó un pequeño error en el código. Cuando hay datos, los mismos vendrás bajo una clave `data` en la respuesta, lo he corregido agregando esto: `$user=$data['data'];` y para imprimir los datos: `printf("<tr><td>%s</td><td>%s</td><td>%s</td></tr>",$user['apellidos'],$user['nombre'],$user['usuario']);`

Answer (score 0):

Alguna consulta no devuelve resultados, puedes usar el operador coalescer si nulo ?? para asignar valores por omisión y así evitar el error.

```
$result = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM user_group_link WHERE group_id='{$group_id}'");
foreach ($result as $row) {
        $user_row=return_field_data($pdo, "users", "id", $row['user_id']??0);
        echo "<tr><td>{$user_row['apellidos']??'Sin datos'}, {$user_row['nombre']??'Sin datos'}</td>
        <td>{$user_row['usuario']??'Sin datos'}</td>
        ";
        }
```