# Ordenación compleja de los resultados de una consulta

Tags: mysql

Teengo una base de datos en la guardo los siguientes datos:

- Fecha, número de caja y número de huevos.

  Quizás en el sistema hay 12 ó 20 cajas funcionando durante unos 20 días cada una, y cada una de ellas empieza y termina en fechas diferentes. Cuando una caja finaliza, ya no aparece en el listado.

Hasta ahora, para hacer una tabla de un parámetro concreto, no tenía problemas. Realizaba una consulta por fecha, o quizás por caja y mostraba los resultados en tablas en plan:

```
 <?php if($query2->num_rows>0):?>

    <table class="table table-sm">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Nº eggs</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody
      <?php while ($r=$query2->fetch_array()):?>
        <tr>
          <td><?php echo $r["eggsdate"]; ?></td>
          <td><?php echo $r["numbereggs"]; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endwhile;?>   
    <?php else:?>
      <p class="alert alert-success">Problems! </p>
    <?php endif;?>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Pero ahora quiero hacer una tabla con todas las cajas activas, como muestro en esta imagen:
[image: Tabla]

No me importa tanto que parezca la fecha de inicio, o que en la cabecera aparezca D1, D2, D3 (días después de la creación de la caja).

Me gustaría empezando a resolver cómo mostrar en la primera columna el número de caja, en la fila de cabecera cada una de las fechas recogidas en estas cajas, y los datos del número de huevos que se recogieron para cada caja en cada fecha.

Mi pregunta es: ¿cómo organizo la consulta y la presentación de los datos para conseguir un formato de tabla de este tipo?

Edito: He seguido las indicaciones de Cedano y he conseguido avances :) Sin embargo, haciendo pruebas, a veces algunas de las filas de la consulta aparecen desordenadas. Es decir, los huevos del D1 no aparecen en la columna D1.

Mi estructura de tablas es esta.

mysql> describe adultcages; (aquí creo cada una de las cajas (cagenumber), cuándo comienzan, terminan y si están activas, por ejemplo)

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| cagenumber | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cagetype   | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cagebegin  | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cageend    | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cageactive | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cagepp     | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ppbatch    | text        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

mysql> describe clusters; (en esta tabla recojo a diario el número de huevos (clustercage). El nombre de la caja (cagenumber) en esta tabla y en el anterior son los mismos.

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| clusterdate | date        | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| cagenumber  | varchar(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| clustercage | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Cuando realizo esta consulta:

```
SELECT c.cagenumber, c.cagebegin, GROUP_CONCAT(p.clustercage SEPARATOR '|') clusters FROM adultcages c LEFT JOIN clusters p ON c.cagenumber=p.cagenumber WHERE c.cageactive LIKE 'Yes' GROUP BY c.cagenumber ORDER BY c.cagenumber
```

Recibo esta tabla:

```
+------------+------------+-------------+
| cagenumber | cagebegin  | clusters    |
+------------+------------+-------------+
| 01-30      | 2017-07-31 | 0|0|18|45   |
| 01-33      | 2017-07-31 | 0|0|32|62   |
| 01-36      | 2017-07-31 | 0|0|31|78   |
| 01-41      | 2017-07-31 | 23|68|130|0 |
+------------+------------+-------------+
```

El único problema es que en la caja 01-41 el orden correcto debería ser 0|23|68|130. Este error (de desorden) se repite en una o más cajas cuando cambio la consulta. Quizás el problema esté al concatenar, o el hecho de que no tengo relacionadas las tablas, pero no estoy seguro. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: Ya que, como dices, las cosas empiezan a complicarse... la bd empieza a crecer, quizá sería bueno que empieces a dividir los datos, de ese modo facilitarás tus consultas y no tendrás datos redundantes. Yo haría dos tablas: una tabla **`cajas`** con los campos `id_caja, caja` y otra tabla **`produccion`** con los campos: `id, id_caja, fecha, total` luego las relacionaría por `id_caja` y aplicaría filtros a la consulta según lo que quiera obtener. El problema es que con `D1, D2, D3...` como lo tienes ahora será imposible manejar en la medida en que pasen los días.

Comment: ¡Muy amable! Precisamente es como tengo organizada ahora las dos tablas en la base de datos. Pero la presentación de la tabla como comento no sería compleja. Me explico. Las cajas están un tiempo funcionando (de 15 a 20 días más o menos), y después terminan y salen del listado (tienen un campo cageactive para mostrar Yes/No y así saber si están activas o no). El problema me viene al intentar mostrar los datos.

Comment: En el planteamiento de la pregunta no se entiende exactamente cuál es el problema, ¿podrías explicar con claridad la forma en que quieres presentar los datos?

Comment: Ya la he actualizado :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### RESPUESTA ACTUALIZADA CON DEMOSTRACIONES DE CÓDIGO

Si tienes un diseño con estas tablas:

- `cajas (id_caja, caja, fecha_inicio)`
- `produccion (id, id_caja, fecha, total)`

Podrías obtener la producción de cada caja con una consulta más o menos como esta:

> **Nota**: La consulta ha sido actualizada, agregando dentro del `GROUP_CONCAT` una sentencia de ordenación, `ORDER BY p.fecha ASC`, la
>   cual agrupará cada columna de `p.total` en el orden indicado.

```
$sql="SELECT 
      c.caja, 
      c.fecha_inicio, 
      GROUP_CONCAT(p.total ORDER BY p.fecha ASC SEPARATOR '|') totales
      FROM cajas c
      LEFT JOIN produccion p ON c.id_caja=p.id_caja
      GROUP BY c.id_caja
      ORDER BY p.fecha";
```

Probando el código en phpfiddle, esta consulta te dará los datos así:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [caja] => Caja1
            [fecha_inicio] => 2017-07-31
            [totales] => 10|1000|14|2|0|976|203
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [caja] => Caja2
            [fecha_inicio] => 2017-08-01
            [totales] => 4|865|789|21|22|5
        )

)
```

Ese array lo puedes trabajar desde PHP para construir una tabla dinámica.

Aquí tienes un ejemplo completo. Creo que los comentarios despejan las principales dudas que puedan surgir. Quizá algunas cosas se puedan mejorar :)

#### Código: [`VER DEMO`](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/p6dg-99h3)

```
<?php

require_once "dBug!.php";

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user_name, $pass_word);

$sql="SELECT c.caja, c.fecha_inicio, GROUP_CONCAT(p.total SEPARATOR '|') totales
      FROM cajas c
      LEFT JOIN produccion p ON c.id_caja=p.id_caja
      GROUP BY c.id_caja
      ORDER BY p.fecha";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);

/**
 *  
 *  RECUPERAR EL RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA
 *  Se crea un array asociativo  de los  resultados usando fechtAll-> y se almacena en $arrDatos
 *  Hay varios métodos para recuperar y leer los datos, ver al respecto la documentación.
 *  En este caso almacenamos los resultados en una variable usando el método fetchAll, 
 *  indicándole que queremos un array asociativo
 *
 **/ 

$arrDatos = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

 /**
  *
  * VERIFICAR EL RESULTADO DE LA CONSULTA Y LEERLO
  * Es importante señalar que en PDO, para verificar si hay valores
  * usar rowCount() no es la práctica recomendada, porque esto se puede hacer
  * verificando los datos mismos, ya que si no hay valores, el objeto devuelto por la consulta será FALSE
  * por tanto, con verificar el valor de $arrDatos será suficiente
  *
  **/


if ($arrDatos)
{

/**
  *
  * MOSTRAR LOS DATOS EN PANTALLA
  * Si hay datos, construiremos una sola variable a la cual le iremos concatenando
  * los diferentes valores contenido en el conjunto de resultados
  * Nótese que hay elementos que se crean fuera del bucle y otros dentro
  * la lógica de dicho procedimiento se sobre-entiende :) 
  *
  **/

    $strHtml="<table border='1'>";

/**
  * Obtenemos la primera fila del array con reset
  * para construir de forma dinámica los encabezados de la tabla
  * dado que la columna totales devuelve los datos así:
  * [totales] => 10|1000|14|2|0|976|203
  * haremos un explode y crearemos los encabezados de los días dinámicamente
  **/      

    $strCabeceras = reset($arrDatos);
    $strDias=explode("|",$strCabeceras["totales"]);

    $strHtml.="<th>CAJA</th>";
    $strHtml.="<th>FECHA INICIO</th>";

    $i = 1;
    foreach($strDias as $dia)
    {
        $strHtml.="<th>D$i</th>";
        $i++;
    }         
    $strHtml.="<tbody>";

    foreach ($arrDatos as $row)
    {
        $strHtml.= "<tr>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["caja"]."</td>";
        $strHtml.= "<td>".$row["fecha_inicio"]."</td>";
        $strDias=explode("|",$row["totales"]);

        foreach($strDias as $dia)
        {
            $strHtml.="<td>$dia</td>";
        }     

        $strHtml.= "</tr>";
    }

    $strHtml.="</tbody>";
    $strHtml.="</table>";
    echo $strHtml;

}else{

    print_r("No se encontraron datos, verifique su conexión o la consulta enviada");   

}

  /**
 *  
 *  CERRAR RECURSOS
 *  Cerramos el objeto de conexión si el caso lo requiere
 *  En PDO no es obligatorio (ver https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967)
 *
 **/ 

$pdo = null;

?>
```

#### `Resultado:`

```html
<table border='1'><th>CAJA</th><th>FECHA INICIO</th><th>D1</th><th>D2</th><th>D3</th><th>D4</th><th>D5</th><th>D6</th><th>D7</th><tbody><tr><td>Caja1</td><td>2017-07-31</td><td>10</td><td>1000</td><td>14</td><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>976</td><td>203</td></tr><tr><td>Caja2</td><td>2017-08-01</td><td>4</td><td>865</td><td>789</td><td>21</td><td>22</td><td>5</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Comment: Genial, Cedano. He conocido (y me he informado más) sobre dBug, PDO, y concatenar en las consultas gracias a tí. He editado mi pregunta porque me he encontrado algunos problemas al realizar la consulta. Al principio pensé que tenía los datos de las tablas mal introducidos, así que las borré, simplifiqué, y comencé de nuevo, pero tengo un problema al recibir desordenados los datos. ¿Podrías echarle un vistazo?

Comment: Me alegro que te haya servido @Alex . Para resolver el problema del orden, sólo tienes que agregar en el `ORDER BY ...` la otra columna en base a la cual quieres que te ordene los datos. Por ejemplo, si es por la columna `clusterdate` de la tabla `clusters` sería más o menos así: `... ORDER BY c.cagenumber, p.clusterdate` de ese modo te ordenará primero por número de caja y luego, dentro de cada cada agrupada, por fecha.

Comment: Sigo con el mismo problema respecto al orden. He hecho consultas sencillas y sin problemas, pero cuando comienzo a hacer JOIN, y a ordenar, todo se desbarata. He profundizado sobre los JOIN y concatenar, y he probado también afinar con CAST, pero sin éxito. La última consulta que he probado es "SELECT c.cagenumber, c.cagebegin, GROUP_CONCAT(p.clustercage SEPARATOR '|') total FROM adultcages c LEFT JOIN clusters p ON c.cagenumber=p.cagenumber GROUP BY c.cagenumber ORDER BY c.cagenumber, p.clusterdate" y lo peor es que la tabla que obtengo es diferente en la consulta usando phpmyadmin o  PHP

Comment: @Alex ya vi el problema, había un pequeño olvido en la consulta, si quieres los datos del `GROUP_BY` ordenados por algún criterio, puedes ponerlo dentro de los paréntesis del mismo, por ejemplo: `SELECT c.caja, c.fecha_inicio, GROUP_CONCAT(p.total ORDER BY p.fecha ASC SEPARATOR '|') totales FROM cajas c INNER JOIN produccion p ON c.id_caja=p.id_caja GROUP BY c.id_caja ORDER BY c.id_caja;`. Puedes verificarlo en **[este demo](http://rextester.com/OJIEJG33033)**, en el cual he introducido los datos de forma desordenada a propósito. Borro el comentario anterior y edito respuesta.

Comment: Ha quedado perfecto, vaya quebradero de cabeza :) Gracias por tu tiempo y tus conocimientos, me han ayudado y animado mucho. Si te parece que con un título diferente puede hacer llegar esta pregunta a más, gente, no tienes más que sugerir uno diferente.¡Un saludo!