# Obtener todos los registros que no estén asociados con un id

Tags: mysql, sql

> Relacionada [¿Como agrupar un registro que se repite, mostrando todos registros distintos que se le asocien?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/97247/6635)

Estoy haciendo una consulta para obtener todos los `clientes` y el `total de cuentas asociadas` pero no quiero mostrar los que ya tengo asociados.

Tengo las siguientes tablas:

```
----dbClientes-----    --------syUsers--------    -----syUsers_WebAccess----
|  id  |  Nombre  |    |  id  |  Nombre      |    | id | idUser | idClient |
-------------------    -----------------------    --------------------------
|  1   |  Juan    |    |  1   | Contabilidad |    | 1  |    1   |    1     |
|  2   |  Victor  |    |  2   | JuankGlezz   |    | 2  |    1   |    3     |
|  3   |  Arturo  |    -----------------------    | 3  |    2   |    1     |
-------------------                               --------------------------
```

Haciendo la siguiente consulta me trae todos los `clientes` con el `total de cuentas asociadas`.

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Nombre, C.id, IFNULL(NC.NumCuentas,0) AS NumCuentas
FROM dbclientes C
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT idClient, count(id) AS NumCuentas FROM syUsers_WebAccess
  ) NC ON NC.idCliente = C.id
```

Me arroja como resultado:

```
Nombre   idCliente  NumCuentas
Juan        1          2
Victor      2          1
Arturo      3          0
```

Ahora quiero aplicar Obtener todos los `clientes` Excepto los `clientes` que tiene asociado `JuankGlezz`, es decir espero como resultado esto:

```
Nombre   idCliente  NumCuentas
Victor      2          1
Arturo      3          0
```

En caso de que el usuario seleccionado fuera `Contabilidad` se mostraria lo siguiente:

```
Nombre   idCliente  NumCuentas
Victor      2          1
```

**¿Como seria la consulta para obtener esos resultados?**, intente con esto, pero solo funciona si solo hay una cuenta asociada.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT C.Nombre, C.id, IFNULL(NC.NumCuentas,0) AS NumCuentas
    FROM dbclientes C
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT idCliente, count(id) AS NumCuentas FROM syUsers_WebAccess
      ) NC ON NC.idCliente = C.id
) TB
WHERE id != (SELECT idCliente FROM syUsers_WebAccess WHERE idUser = 48)
```

> **Nota:** No puedo simplemente poner el `idClient`, debido a que desde la aplicación obtengo solo el `idUser`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lo más simple para esto es usar `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.Nombre, C.id, IFNULL(NC.NumCuentas,0) AS NumCuentas
FROM dbclientes C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  idClient, 
                    count(id) AS NumCuentas 
            FROM syUsers_WebAccess
            GROUP BY idClient) NC 
    ON NC.idCliente = C.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM syUsers_WebAccess
                 WHERE idUser = 2 --JuanKGlezz
                 AND idCliente = NC.idCliente)
;
```

[**Acá hay una demo**](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=bdc67ba9e39e92dc42438c0a7e0f5fd9) de esto.

Comment: [Encontré esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2246793/3791844)
 (un poco vieja ya) donde se dice que `In MySQL, NOT EXISTS is a little bit less efficient`, pero no estoy seguro de que aún aplique

Answer (score 1):

Otra solución es hacer un `LEFT JOIN` a la table `sysUsers_WebAcces` y excluir todos los `clientes` donde el `idUser = 2`

Así por ejemplo:

```
SELECT C.Nombre, C.id, SUM(IF(ISNULL(NC.id), 0, 1)) AS NumCuentas
FROM dbClientes C
  LEFT JOIN syUsers_WebAccess AS NC
    ON NC.idCliente = C.id
WHERE C.id NOT IN (
  SELECT idCliente 
  FROM syUsers_WebAccess 
  WHERE idUser = 2)
GROUP BY C.id
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=62a59eda860312265683d5b57c7e1dc0)</kbd>

*PD*: Podrías reemplazar el `NOT IN` por el `NOT EXISTS` de la [respuesta de @Lamak](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/97367/16597)

Comment: De nada. Pero esto no entrega lo solicitado en la pregunta