# ayuda con php y base de datos

Tags: php

tengo una consulta la cual me arroja mes total y departamento
solo quiero acomodar en una tabla ejemplo

```
             ENERO   FEBRERO MARZO  ABRIL  ETC
VACACIONES    100      200    300   400
SUELDO        1000    1200    1250
```

a ver si me pueden apoyar gracias

Comment: serás tan amable de agregar la consulta que has hecho hasta el momento?

Comment: Yo diría que no cargues demasiado a la base de datos armando una consulta complicada. Puedes traer los datos de la forma más simple posible y luego trabajarlos por programación. Las bases de datos no son un lenguaje de programación y muchas veces uno quiere que la BD te resuelva todo. Incluso a veces se sacrifica al modelo de datos porque se le pide más de lo que él (puede) o (debe) dar. [Aquí hay un ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93455/29967) de un resultado más o menos complejo que es traído de forma simple y trabajado por programación.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href="estilos/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

<script src="/JS/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/JS/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
    <nav>

<h2>pruena</h2>
<DIV align="left">
 <h2>rwsultado</h2>      
</DIV>
    </nav>
</header>



<table border="1" align="center" bgcolor="#CBCBCB" width="1280">
  <tr bgcolor="#DBDBDB">
    <td><strong>Nombre</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Enero</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Nombre</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Febrero</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Junio</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Julio</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Agosto</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Septiembre</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Octubre</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Noviembre</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Diciembre</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Total</strong></td>

  </tr>




<form> 


<header>

<div align="left">
  <input type="date" required id="start_date" name="start_date"> 
  <input type="hidden" id="form_sent" name="form_sent" value="true">
  <input type="submit" class="btn-primary" id="btn_submit" value="Crear Poliza">

<br/>
</div>
</header>



  <?php if (isset($_GET['form_sent']) && $_GET['form_sent'] == "true") 
{?>
  <?php 

$timestamp = strtotime($_GET['start_date']);
$inicio = strftime("%m/%d/%Y", $timestamp);
$muestra = strftime("%d/%m/%Y", $timestamp);
echo $muestra;




include_once('connections/connect.php');?>


  <?php

$meses=array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril", "mayo","junio", "julio", "agosto","septiembre","octubre","noviembre","diciembre");
$query = "SELECT  

 CUENTAS_CO_1.NOMBRE
  ,SUM(SALDOS_CO_1.MES   ) AS MES

,SALDOS_CO_1.CARGOS
FROM CUENTAS_CO  CUENTAS_CO_1

  INNER JOIN SALDOS_CO SALDOS_CO_1 ON   (SALDOS_CO_1.CUENTA_ID = CUENTAS_CO_1.CUENTA_ID)

WHERE ( SALDOS_CO_1.ANO = 2017) and CUENTAS_CO_1.CUENTA_PADRE_ID in (10258,10270)

GROUP BY    
CUENTAS_CO_1.NOMBRE
,SALDOS_CO_1.CARGOS,SALDOS_CO_1.MES 

 ORDER BY MES ";


$result = ibase_query($conn, $query);





?> 


  <?php  
while($row = IBASE_fetch_assoc($result))  

 {

echo '<td>' .$row['NOMBRE']. '</td>'; 
echo "<td>".$meses[$row['MES']-1]."</td>";
echo '<td>' . number_format($row['CARGOS'], 2) . '</td>';
echo "</td>";     
echo '</tr>';

if ($meses = 'Febrero');


}





}




  ?>


  <?

</table>
</body>
<div class ="footer"> 
by Gustavo Moreno

</html>
```

Comment: y esto es...? una respuesta una pregunta?

Comment: Soy nuevo aún no sé cómo seguir o contestar pero ese es el código que tengo para ordenar saldos por meses

Answer (score 0):

TABLA MYSQL

ID MES    TIPO

1   ENERO  VACASIONES
2   MARZO  ESTUDIOS
3   MARZO  VACASIONES

```
SELECT mes AS mes,COUNT(id) AS registros FROM MYSQL WHERE id NOT NULL GROUP BY mes
```