# Tabla HTML desde mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, html5, array

Si bien, lei y busque mucho antes de preguntar (si duplico pregunta, les pido mis disculpas), no encontre algun ejemplo que se adapte a lo que necesito.
Tengo que crear una tabla html dinamica. Este requerimiento basado en una idea de agendamiento de horas para una clinica. 
El tema debe funcionar asi: Cada clinica puede tener 1 o mas box(oficinas de atencion) a pacientes y se debe listar el horario de atencion y los box (que son dinamicos) pero con el rango de horarios de atencion de cada clinica.
Ej: 
Clinica 1, horario de atencion desde las 08:00 hasta las 20:00 hrs.
Clinica 1, tiene 3 box de atencion, cada uno con sus propios horarios reservados (cada clinica puede tener uno o mas box de atencion).
Todos los datos, vienen desde BD mysql, los cuales expondre ahora.

```
<?php
  $consulta = "SELECT
  horario_ini,
  horario_fin

  FROM horarios

  WHERE id_cl = '$id_us'";

  $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
  if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
      $var1 = $row['horario_ini'];
      $var2 = $row['horario_fin'];
    }
  }
  //aqui obtengo los rango de horarios de atencion de cada clinica
  $fechaInicio = new DateTime($var1);
  $fechaFin = new DateTime($var2);
  $fechaFin = $fechaFin->modify(' +15 minutes');

  $rangoFechas = new DatePeriod($fechaInicio, new DateInterval('PT15M'), $fechaFin);

  $consulta = "SELECT
  MIN(hora_ini) AS minimo,
  MAX(hora_fin) AS maximo
  FROM agenda

  WHERE id_cl = '$id_us' AND sucursal = 4 ";

  $resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
  if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
      $hora_inicio = $row['minimo'];
      $hora_fin = $row['maximo'];
    }
  }
  //aqui obtengo la hora minima y maxima para mostrar como disponible u ocupado en la tabla.
   $timeIn = new DateTime($hora_inicio);
   $timeOut = new DateTime($hora_fin);

 ?>
```

Luego genero la tabla HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-4">
 <div class="white-box">
  <h3 class="box-title">HORAS DISPONIBLES</h3>
   <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped">
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>HORA</th>
       <th>INGRESAR</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
     <?php
     foreach($rangoFechas as $fecha){
      $time = $fecha->format("H:i");
      $arrTimes[] = $time;
      if ($time >= $timeIn->format("H:i") && $time <= $timeOut->format("H:i")){
     ?>
      <tr border: 1px solid black;>
       <td style="background-color: #ffb3b3; color: black"><?=$time?></td>
       <td style="background-color: #ffb3b3;"><a href='#' style='cursor: pointer' class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded btn-danger">OCUPADO</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }else{
      ?>
      <tr>
       <td style="color: black"><?=$time?></td>
       <td><a href='#' style='cursor: pointer' class="btn btn-xs btn-rounded btn-success">ASIGNAR</a></td>
      </tr>
      <?php
      }
     }

     ?>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que obtengo con lo anterior es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Resultados esperados: 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe mencionar, que cada clinica puede tener 1 o X box de atencion, pero que cada clinica tiene un solo rango de horas de atencion. La cantidad de box que tiene cada clinica se obtiene de la siguiente manera:

```
$consulta = "SELECT
id AS box_id,
nombre AS box_nombre
FROM box_atencion

WHERE id_cl = '$id_us'";//donde $id_us es el id del cliente o clinica

$resultado = $conexion->query($consulta);
if ($resultado->num_rows > 0){
 while ($row = $resultado->fetch_array()) {
  $box_id = $row['box_id'];
  $box_nombre = $row['box_nombre'];
 }
}
```

Si alguien, tiene alguna idea de como hacer esto o me oriente a como hacerlo, se lo agradeceria muchismo.
De antemano, muchas gracias a todos.
Saludos.

Comment: Lo que planteas se parece mucho [a esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/93455/29967). Creo que si aplicas la misma lógica podrías obtenerlo fácilmente, además con una sola consulta que haga `JOIN` de las diferentes tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano he seguido todo como esta en el ejemplo indicado, pero me tira todo en una sola tabla (hacia abajo) ademas no me lista el nombre de los BOX. En si, el ejemplo funciona, me muestra las horas desocupadas y ocupadas, pero siempre todo hacia abajo. La idea tambien era, no mostrar todo el rango de horas por cada box, lo cual tampoco he podido lograr.

Comment: No sé si te diste cuenta de que en la consulta estoy usando `GROUP_CONCAT`. La clave está ahí, yo traigo los valores agrupados usando un separador y luego los trabajo por programación. La verdad no he tenido tiempo de revisar a fondo tu problema. Dime si en tu intento usaste `GROUP_CONCAT` o no, porque esa es una clave importante para que funcione.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder. No use GROUP_CONCAT ya que formule la consulta mysql de una perspectiva diferente y los resultados de dicha consulta, son los que necesito para la muestra en la tabla HTML.

Comment: Entiendo. Tendría que detenerme a analizar a fondo el problema para ver cómo puedo ayudarte, sólo que ahora mismo no podría hacerlo. Dejemos la pregunta ahí, y te prometo revisarla cuando pueda... o bien otra persona podría darte una respuesta adecuada. Sugerí mi enlace porque leyendo la pregunta por encima me pareció que era casi la misma situación.

Comment: @A.Cedano muchas gracias por tu tiempo y disposicion a ayudarme. Se agradece. En si, la situaciones es muy parecida, pero el resultado esperado varia un poco en cuanto a detalles que son diferentes, como te comente antes, solo necesito que se repita una vez el rango de horas de atencion, la imagen que esta en la pregunta, es el resultado, que necesito. Agradezco nuevamente la ayuda brindada. Saludos.