# ¿Es óptimo abrir y cerrar la conexión a la BBDD en php cada vez que requiero de su uso?

Tags: php, mysql, webservice, web, pdo

Utilizo la conexión a la base de datos para saber los usuarios que tengo guardados y así utilizarlos para validar el login. ¿Es recomendable que por cada petición (login) haya una conexión y una desconexión?

Adjunto código:

```
require_once "conn.php";
function validUser(&$error){
if((!isset($_POST['user'])) || (!isset($_POST['pass']))){
    $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
    return null;
}
$user = $_POST['user'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];
if(($user == '') || ($pass == '')){
    $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
    return null;
}else{

    $con = connection();
    $sql = "SELECT name FROM usuarios WHERE name = :user AND password = :pass";
    $query = $con->prepare($sql);
    $query-> bindParam(':user', $user);
    $query-> bindParam(':pass', $pass);
    $query-> execute();
    $contador = $query -> rowCount();
    if($contador != 1){
        $error[0] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos.";
        return null;
    }
    $con = null;
    return $user;
}
}
```

Comment: Es recomendable siempre cerrar las conexiones para no sobrecargar al servidor, sobre todo si tu página recibe muchas peticiones al día.
El no cerrar las conexiones a la base de datos podría llegar a ocasionar que la aplicación colapse o no permita abrir nueva conexiones a la base de datos. Saludos.

Comment: El Manual de PHP dice, al menos en el caso de PDO, que la conexión se cierra al terminar el script que la usa. Puedes cerrarla si quieres por costumbre de programación, pero si la dejas abierta tampoco pasa nada. [Mira esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967), allí cito lo que dice el Manual al respecto. Puedes incluso usar conexiones persistentes (yo las uso en un sitio web que consulta constantemente a la BD) y no hay ningún problema. La clave sería tener una Clase que no cree nuevos objetos de conexión si ya existe uno activo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como todo en la vida: depende. No todo es blanco o negro y no hay una respuesta concreta para una pregunta como ésta. Va a depender de muchos factores como por ejemplo:

- ¿Cuántas conexiones esperas y cuántas conexiones simultáneas permite la base de datos?
- ¿Qué lenguaje de programación y qué base de datos estás usando?
- ¿Cómo de rápida debe ser la respuesta del sistema?
- ¿El servidor de tu aplicación y de la base de datos están en la misma máquina?
- Etc.

En PHP en particular, a no ser que definas una conexión persistente, la conexión a la base de datos se va a cerrar automáticamente al final del script, por lo que abrir/cerrar conexiones varias veces en la vida de una página puede ser excesivo: vas a ralentizar la página y consumir recursos de manera innecesaria.

Pero eso no quiere decir que no lo hagas: si tu sistema no necesita respuestas en tiempo real y la velocidad no es un factor crítico, la diferencia entre abrir/cerrar múltiples conexiones o mantener una abierta durante la vida del script va a ser casi despreciable.

Mi recomendación para el caso que planteas sería: déjalo como está. Creo que estás intentando optimizar de manera prematura algo que todavía no sabes si va a ser un problema. Céntrate en otras partes del sistema y si luego ves que abrir/cerrar múltiples conexiones te va a crear problemas de algún tipo (seguramente no), puedes probar otras opciones (p.e. una única conexión por script que la necesite o una fábrica de conexiones).

Citando a Knuth: "*El verdadero problema es que los programadores gastan demasiado tiempo preocupándose de la eficiencia en los lugares equivocados en los momentos equivocados; la optimización prematura es  la raíz de todos los males (o al menos de la mayoría) en programación.*"

Comment: “*El arte de atacar miniproblemas con toda la energía agudizará nuestro talento para los problemas reales. … No deberíamos abandonar el arte por el arte; no deberíamos sentirnos culpables de hacer programas sólo por divertirnos*" ([ALGOL 60 confidential](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/72129/))