# Cerrar conexion PDO a sql server correctamente desde php

Tags: php, pdo

Tuve que incorporar PDO, php8 db sqlserver 2016 pero no lo entiendo del todo. Cree la clase Cconexion::conectar(); en conexion.php
Funcionó, pero no creo sea la forma de abrir y cerrar la conexión correctamente.

Copio algo de mi código :

```html
<?php
  session_start();     
  include_once 'conexion.php';

  $usuario = $_POST["usuario"];
  $password = $_POST["password"];
  $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;

  $pdo=Cconexion::conectar();
  
  $stmt = $pdo -> query("SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario' AND password = '$password'");
  $resultado = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
   
  // Verificando si el usuario existe en la base de datos.

  if($resultado){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit();
  }else{
    session_destroy();
    echo 'Usuario ó password incorrecto ! , <a href="inicio.php">Click aquí para reintentar</a>.<br/>';
  }
  
  $stmt->closeCursor();
  $stmt=null;
  $pdo=null;
  
?>
```

Está bien asi  ....? o hay una forma para aprender mas optimizada de crear el objeto y luego cerrarlo ?

Comment: Con esto basta: `$stmt=null;
  $pdo=null;`, pero deberías ponerlo antes del `exit()`

Comment: gracias ! No se xq no me aparece para puntuar la respuesta ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A no ser que tu conexión a PDO sea persistente, la misma se cerrará cuando el script que la abrió o la incluyó haya terminado, o lo que es lo mismo, cuando ya no haya ninguna referencia a la conexión. Para más detalles sobre esto, consulta [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50097/29967) (y los enlaces que hay en ella) a la pregunta: *[¿Es necesario cerrar una conexión con PDO luego de ejecutar una sentencia?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/50083/29967)*. Aún así, hay discusiones sobre si es mejor cerrarla de todos modos o no. Algunos dicen que sí, que conviene hacerlo, porque ese recurso se libera de inmediato sin exponerte a fugas de memoria, otros dicen que no hace falta, que PHP se encarga de liberar el recurso apenas el script termina.

Si por algún motivo quisieras cerrar la conexión, bastaría con asignarle el valor `null`, sin más. Pero esto debe ir en un lugar lógico. Si usas redirecciones, debes hacer todo lo que se necesite hacer antes, porque el código irá a otra parte. Por tanto, en el contexto de tu código deberías cerrarla en las dos partes: en el `if` debe ocurrir antes del `exit()` y en el `else` también debes cerrarla.

Algo así:

```
  if($resultado){
    $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario;
    $stmt=null;
    $pdo=null;
    header('Location: index.php'); 
    exit();
  }else{
    session_destroy();
    $stmt=null;
    $pdo=null;
    echo 'Usuario ó password incorrecto ! , <a href="inicio.php">Click aquí para reintentar</a>.<br/>';
  }
```

Como nota final, asoma una duda de *coherencia* en este código. ¿Por qué no hay redirección en el caso del `else`?

Comment: Si, muchas gracias por la explicación, me aclara bastante. Respecto a los lugares lógicos copié la 1er versión de cuando encontré lo de asignarle null ... luego lo ubiqué más correctamente. Me quedaba la duda si con ello alcanzaba y si era la manera "prolija" de hacerlo. En el else, al ser un login sencillo (mas tarde cambié el where usando ? ? para evitar injects) no quise ocuparme de hacer una página de error, y preferí que se muetre el link para volver a inicio.php y que el usuario prefiera tipear correctamente a ir y venir ....